# Adding a CSS class to select_month

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following `select_month` helper. I want to add a `class` but it's not producing the *HTML*.

```
select_month(Date.today,
    :add_month_numbers => true,
    :html => { :class => 'col-xs-3' }
)
```

I've also tried it with a hash as some solutions suggest but I get a syntax error:

```
select_month(Date.today,
    :add_month_numbers => true,
    { :class => 'col-xs-3' }
)
```

and:

```
select_month(Date.today,
    :add_month_numbers => true,
    :class => 'col-xs-3'
)
```

Not sure I really understand when and how to format it with a hash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the second and third params are both hashes, you need to wrap the second one in curly braces

```
select_month(Date.today,
    {:add_month_numbers => true},
    :class => '.col-xs-3'
)
```

You are only allowed to omit the curly braces on the last hash argument of a given function. For `select_month` here is the definition:

```
select_month(date, options = {}, html_options = {}) public
```

So as you can see, both `options` and `html_options` accept a hash. To keep Ruby from getting confused, simply put the second (or both) arguments inside curly braces.

Comment: This is the answer. Than you!